# How can I quickly reformat a CSV file into SQL format in Vim?

Tags: mysql, csv, vim

I have a CSV file that I need to format (i.e., turn into) a SQL file for ingestion into MySQL. I am looking for a way to add the text delimiters (single quote) to the text, but not to the numbers, booleans, etc. I am finding it difficult because some of the text that I need to enclose in single quotes have commas themselves, making it difficult to key in to the commas for search and replace. Here is an example line I am working with:

```
1239,1998-08-26,'Severe Storm(s)','Texas,Val Verde,"DEL RIO, PARKS",'No',25,"412,007.74"
```

This is FEMA data file, with 131246 lines, I got off of data.gov that I am trying to get into a MySQL database. As you can see, I need to insert a single quote after Texas and before Val Verde, so I tried:

```
s/,/','/3
```

But that only replaced the first occurrence of the comma on the first three lines of the file. Once I get past that, I will need to find a way to deal with "DEL RIO, PARKS", as that has a comma that I do not want to place a single quote around.

So, is there a "nice" way to manipulate this data to get it from plain CSV to a proper SQL format?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL has the functionality built in to read in a CSV. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: That's pretty nice, but it seems to have truncated my 131246 line file down to 959 lines.

Comment: Is it a typo that `'Texas,Val Verde` does not end with a closing single-quote?

Comment: Not a typo. I am in the middle of editing the file, and that single quote before Texas is the last single quote I have been able to successfully place in the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to bring this to a close, I ended up using @Eric Andres idea, which was the MySQL load data option:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE MYTABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The initial .csv file still took a little massaging, but not as much as I were to do it by hand.

When I commented that the LOAD DATA had truncated my file, I was incorrect. I was treating the file as a typical .sql file and assumed the "ID" column I had added would auto-increment. This turned out to not be the case. I had to create a quick script that prepended an ID to the front of each line. After that, the LOAD DATA command worked for all lines in my file. In other words, all data has to be in place within the file to load before the load, or the load will not work.

Thanks again to all who replied, and @Eric Andres for his idea, which I ultimately used.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are notoriously dicey to parse. Different programs export CSV in different ways, possibly including strangeness like embedding new lines within a quoted field or different ways of representing quotes within a quoted field. You're better off using a tool specifically suited to parsing CSV -- perl, python, ruby and java all have CSV parsing libraries, or there are command line programs such as csvtool or ffe.

If you use a scripting language's CSV library, you may also be able to leverage the language's SQL import as well. That's overkill for a one-off, but if you're importing a lot of data this way, or if you're transforming data, it may be worthwhile.

I think that I would also want to do some troubleshooting to find out why the CSV import into MYSql failed.

Answer (score 0):

I would take an approach like this:

:%s/,\("[^"]*"\|[^,"]*\)/,'\1'/g

:%s/^\("[^"]*"\|[^,"]*\)/'\1'/g

In words, look for a double quoted set of characters or , \|, a non-double quoted set of characters beginning with a comma and replace the set of characters in a single quotation.

Next, for the first column in a row, look for a double quoted set of characters or , \|, a non-double quoted set of characters beginning with a comma and replace the set of characters in a single quotation.

Comment: Well, I do not exactly account for the non-text columns in this csv.

Comment: You probably want to create substitution arguments that are data type specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try the csv plugin. It allows to convert the data into other formats. The help includes an example, how to convert the data for importing it into a database